# What exactly is happening here, when I'm creating a thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Threads in Java can be defined in two ways:

1. You can implement the Runnable interface.
2. You can extend the Thread class itself.

What is this way to create threads?

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(10000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            finish();
        }
    }
};

t.start();
```

Is this an anonymous class? This code works properly, and I did test this code. But I don't understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this anonymous class ???????????

Yes this is anonymous inline class implementation. This is used when you want to create a thread object of your class locally using the inline class implementation.

Comment: i agree your words but my question is that 
"java thread require to create by extend the Thread class but I did not any extend any class " I am just use anonymous class....
In other word anonymous class mean to extend any super class?????

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code creates an [Anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

*Is this anonymous class ?* yes it anonymous class

read this for understanding about an [anonymous class](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-an-anonymous-class-in-java.html)
and good example [here](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/10/what-is-anonymous-class-in-java.html)

Comment: here are the reference you give " An anonymous class in Java is a class not given a name and is both declared and instantiated in a single statement. You should consider using an anonymous class whenever you need to create a class that will be instantiated only once."
But i did not provide any constructor here in my code?????

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in some sense equivalent to having a separate class, defined like this.

```
public class SleepyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(10000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

then having code like this.

```
Thread t = new SleepyThread();
t.start();
```

but because you only need this class in one place, it's not necessary to give it a name, or give it its own source file.  You can simply inline the class definition in the way you've done it.

The compiler will still make a class file for it, with a name something like `MyClass$1.class`, where `MyClass` is the class within which you're using this.  It's only "anonymous" in the sense that you have not given it a name.  It's still a fully fledged class in every way.

Comment: :) Now I get some understanding about the anonymous class...
 thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This is what we call anonymous classes and you are right about this:--

Threads in Java can be defined in two ways:

You can implement the Runnable interface.

You can extend the Thread class itself.

Actually anonymous class you created internally a subclass which is extending Thread class.
So here your thread defined by 2nd option..!